# Couple of questions in hibernate ORM.

Tags: java, hibernate

```
<hibernate mapping package="org.hibernate.tutorial.domain">

    <class name="Event" table"Events">
       <id name="id" column="EVENT_ID">
          <generator class ="native"/>
       </id>

       <property name="date" type="timestamp" column="EVENT_DATE"/>
       <property name="title"/>

       </class>

</hibernate-mapping>
```

http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.3/reference/en/html/tutorial.html#tutorial-firstapp
I was going through this article on hibernate.

1. Is this the best guide for starters.
2. What does `generator class ="native"` mean and what does it do?
3. why is the id declared with id tag, but the other declared with
   property tag.
4. do people still use xml file for mapping class with the table. Is it an old fashioned way.

Answer (score 2):

1. Probably.
2. It means to use the database's "native" id methodology, like a sequence in Oracle or an `auto_increment` in MySql, etc.
3. Because one's an ID and the others are properties.
4. Yes. Yes, but it's also preferable in some situations, e.g., wanting/needing to decouple the source from Hibernate or keeping the DB config in one place (XML files in a single directory instead of in source files wherever they may be).

Answer (score 2):

1. That's a very subjective answer.  I would start from a JPA guide myself.
2. Native means it will use the generation method that is specific to the database.  For instance, for mysql it will use auto-increment.  For oracle it could use sequences.
3. Hibernate requires each entity to have an id.  Use the id element to mark it.
4. Most people now use annotations instead.  There's the advantage there that you can use JPA annotations and not be tied to hibernate.  Still there is a place in the world for XML config, for instance, to map beans you don't have source access to.

Comment: Hey, that is the first real advantage of Hibernate annotations which I heard about. I prefer xml mapping files, because there you can have different mappings for different databases without changing a single line of Java code, they give a good overview about the mapping, and they help in the right way of database design (database first, Java pojos later). But mostly it is a question of personal taste.

Comment: Hehe.  I'm a big believer in Pojos first, db later :)  That's more religion than taste though.

Answer (score 1):

Answers to your questions:

1)Is this the best guide for starters.
   - It is an official and first ever documentation for hibernate. I rather prefer "Hibernate in Action"

2) There are several `generators` in hibernate, depends on requirement we need to choose the proper one, Basically it is used to generate the primary key. For example if you use `generator="assigned"` i.e., you need to manually assign a primary key before you call `session.save(entity)`. Here `native` means hibernate will take care of generating primary key based on the database dialect you provided in configuration. It uses sequence if you use oracle and auto_increment if you use mysql or postgres

3) id denotes the primary key, others are properties, Hope this is for a convention.

4) Older applications still uses xmls. It is better to start with xmls while learning then convert them to annotations.